# Removing roles from a user without using UserManager

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-mvc

Is it possible to remove roles from a user by only using

```
ApplicationUser user = _DbContext.Users
                .Where(u => u.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();

user.Roles.Clear();
```

For some reason, user.Roles.Clear() isn't working. I'm remembering to do

```
_DbContext.SaveChanges();
```

after, but the roles aren't being removed from the DB?